# Animate a static property?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Just getting into JavaFX, really liking it, but I'm not quite sure of how to animate an AnchorPane.leftAnchor property.

Currently, I'm using a Timeline to animate the Node.translateXProperty(), and that gives me a nice smooth animation. However, although my node appears to move, it seems that in terms of receiving mouse clicks, it has not moved. So really, what I'd like to do is animate the node's AnchorPane.leftAnchor static property, is that possible?

Ideally, I'd like to keep my Timeline, as it's doing other things too, so..

1) Is it possible to animate a static property in the same way I can animate a regular property like this:

```
new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(node.translateXProperty(), from, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH))
```

2) If that's not possible, can I translate mouse clicks to match up to the translated position?

Cheers

Garry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you animate the `translateX` and `translateY` properties, then the mouse coordinates on the node that's animated, retrieved by `MouseEvent.getX()` and `MouseEvent.getY()`, will be local to the coordinate system of that node: i.e. they won't be affected by the change in location of the node itself. The same is true if you animate the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties (which you would do if you animated the `AnchorPane.leftAnchor` "property").

You can transform a point in a node's local coordinate system to its parent's coordinate system by calling [`Node.localToParent(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToParent-double-double-).

Note there are other similar methods on `Node`, such as `localToScene` and `localToScreen`, and also some convenience methods on the `MouseEvent`: `getSceneX()`, `getScreenX()`, and similarly for `y`.

To answer your actual question (though I suspect it's redundant, maybe...), you can create a new property and "animate" that property. Then add a listener to it and update the `leftAnchor` when it changes. This SSCCE demonstrates this technique (though you can use a [`TranslateTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) instead and get the mouse coordinates in exactly the same way).

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimateXAnchor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Region rect = new Region();
        rect.setPrefSize(100,  100);
        rect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornflowerblue;");

        rect.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            double x = e.getX();
            double y = e.getY();
            System.out.printf("Mouse click in local coordinates: [%.1f, %.1f]%n", x, y);

            Point2D clickInParent = rect.localToParent(x, y);
            System.out.printf("Mouse click in parent coordinates: [%.1f, %.1f]%n%n", clickInParent.getX(), clickInParent.getY());

        });

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(rect, 10.0);

        DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        x.addListener((obs, oldX, newX) -> AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(rect, newX.doubleValue()));

        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(x, 0)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(x, 400))
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        animation.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you James, the second part of your answer, with the creation of a new property was the exact solution I needed, it works perfectly. Thanks!